# Delphi Firemonkey: Different rendering on Android and Windows

Tags: android, windows, delphi, firemonkey

We have the following code...

```
  if aForceRebuild or (not FHasBitmap) then
  try
    if TFile.Exists(FFileName) then
    begin
      FRectangle.WrapMode:=TImageWrapMode.Fit; //Try to force correct drawing in Android
      FRectangle.Bitmap.LoadThumbnailFromFile(FFilename, FRectangle.Width-THUMB_MARGIN, FRectangle.Height-THUMB_MARGIN);
      FHasBitmap:=True;
    end
  except
    Raise;
  end;
```

...which on Windows draws correctly the bitmap keeping the proportion ratios of the loaded thumbnail while on Android, the output image is stretched in order to cover the entire rectangle.

*How can we fix this in order to have correct rendering (ie. keeping the aspect ratio) on any platform?*

Notes:

- FRectangle is a `TImage` object.
- `FRectangle.WrapMode:=TImageWrapMode.Fit` is called also at `FRectangle`'s creation. No luck.
- Versions: Delphi XE6, Windows 7, Android 4.2

Comment: Draw the Bitmap on the Canvas yourself and calculate the correct drawing rectangle

Comment: You might have to calculate the correct ratio / bounding box yourself, but can you [add a report to the Quality database](https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) please? Good bug reports should get addressed.

Comment: By default Firemonkey doesn't draw the Windows version with 3D. While the Android and IOS versions are drawn with OpenGL. Hence the reason the rendering is different. You can enable 3D on Windows if you like but it doesn't do anti-aliasing by default.

Comment: @FMXExpress: I understand that, but I don't want to make Windows in the same way with Android but in the other way around. Android has buggy rendering AFAIS.

Comment: You can try using a native control for painting: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/